# IQueryable OrderBy expression in .NET core

Tags: c#, iqueryable, .net-core

In a .Net core library it does not allow to call `IQueryable.OrderBy` with an expression as param

This is an example of the code:

```
public class Elem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public static IQueryable<Elem> SortById(IQueryable<Elem> paramSequence)
    {
        return paramSequence.OrderBy(x => x.Id);  //this gives error
    }
}
```

I have added the `System.Linq.Expression` package. This is my project file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
        "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.10"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.5": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `System.Linq.Expressions` contains `IQueryable<T>` and `Expression<TDelegate>`. But for your code to work, you also need the type that contains `IQueryable` LINQ extensions methods: `Queryable`. This type is in the `System.Linq.Queryable` package.

Since `System.Linq.Queryable` depends on `System.Linq.Expressions`, you can replace the `System.Linq.Expressions` line in your project.json with:

```
"System.Linq.Queryable": "4.0.1-rc2-24027"
```

Comment: Thanks! it works now (it added package "System.Linq.Queryable": "4.0.0" to me but also works...)